# How do I include a variable in cmd command?

Tags: cmd, hostname, mpiexec

For example, I want the process "myexe.exe" to run on any host computer. So i want hostname to be evaluated on each computer and inserted into the command. Ideally i want this all done in one line. I tried the following code.

```
mpiexec -n 8 -hosts 1 %hostname% myexe.exe myinputfile.txt
```

But i got this error

```
... unable to get host address for %hostname% (11001)
```

So it doesn't appear to have evaluated hostname properly. How do i get hostname to be evaluated properly in the command?

Comment: Why do you think just making something up would work. Type `set` to see what's available. See `set /?` for more at the end. Also see https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/listenvironmentexe-list-system-user.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'making something up'. Do you mean I made up 'hostname'? I used hostname, because it provides the computer name when you execute hostname. I thought there maybe a way to extract the output of that command into a variable in my mpiexec command. Anyway, seems as though there is a variable that already has the computer name called COMPUTERNAME, thanks for suggeting set. So i just swapped that with hostname and my command now works fine.  But for interest it would be nice to know if i could insert the output of hostname directly into a variable in the mpiexec command.

Comment: Type `For /?` and specifically `for /f` for parsing command output.

Comment: You need to be an admin to access this share `dir \\localhost\C$` (or `dir \\127.0.0.1\C$`)will list C: drive on any local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `localhost` instead.

But, on Windows (implied by the `cmd` tag) you probably should use:

```
mpiexec -n 8 -hosts 1 %COMPUTERNAME% myexe.exe myinputfile.txt
```

The magic for setting a variable from the output of `hostname` is:

```
FOR /F %A IN ('hostname') DO (SET "V=%~A")
```

In a .bat file script, double the PERCENT SIGN character.

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('hostname') DO (SET "V=%%~A")
```